# rails - calculated column on model issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want to create a calculated column on a model, which is not in the database.

```
class Result < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessor :calculated_duration


  def calculated_duration
    (build_start_time - build_end_time)
  end

end
```

This is what I have, and I am trying to access it like this:

```
@results = Result.all.order(:build_number)
@results.calculated_duration
```

I'm getting a no method error:
undefined method `calculated_duration'

Can anyone suggest why?

Answer (score 2):

Because you're calling an instance method on an `ActiveRecord::Collection`

```
@result = Result.first
@result.calculated_duration
```

will work

Comment: is there a way to get it calculated for all, could I call this:
@result = @all_results.pluck(:build_start_time, :calculated_duration)

Comment: This will fetch the calculated values Result.all.order(:build_number).to_json({:methods=>[:calculated_duration]})